# Numpy array vectorized intersection

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, vectorization

I have a 3d numpy array that represents the `user id` obtained from my classifier with shape `(NxKxM)` and I would like to compute the jaccard index (len intersection /len union) in order to check the ratio of overlap during my groupkfold. I need to compute this function on the N (number of hyperparams) and M(number or iterations) axis, while `K` is the CV folds number. I would like to have something like:

> A[0][0][:] is compared with A[1:][:][:], A[0][1][:] is compared with A[1:][:][:] and A[0][2][:] is compared with A[1:][:][:] for the first level and so on iteratively. (in case of k=3)

I have tried a nested for cycle but of course the code is extremely slow, so far I have this situation:

```
for elem in range(len(total_users_splits)):
    for subelem in range(elem+1,len(total_users_splits)):
        for i in range(n_splits):
            for j in range(n_splits):
                first = b[elem][i]
                second = b[subelem][j]
                total_num = len(np.union1d(first,second))
                intersect_len = len(np.intersect1d(first,second))
                X.append(intersect_len/total_num)
overlap = {'overlap_ratio_mean_uids':np.nanmean(X),
           'overlap_ratio_std_uids':np.nanstd(X),
           'overlap_ratio_max_uids':np.max(X),
           'overlap_ratio_min_uids':np.min(X)}
```

`total_user_splits` is a list of dimension NxM and `n_splits` is k.

The code is really slow but I don't know how to apply `np.intersect` in a vectorized way

Comment: Union can be calculated by `total_num = len(first) + len(second) - intersect_len`, which may save some time. Converting your array into a list of set objects and using set.intersection is the best choice I can think of.